# how can i get a string or stream of the POST body?

Tags: servicestack

In serveicestack I want to retrieve the request body of a POST in my service.  How would I setup my end point.
I know I can use  base.Request.GetRawBody (); but is there another way?

Comment: Do you really need the raw request body text within a specific *service* implementation (as opposed to accessing it from a request filter, etc.)? I don't think this would match up well with the message-based design of ServiceStack.

Comment: This project Is to manage testing client side calls that can very greatly based on vendor configuration. So I don't see and alternative other then getting the body.  All the management api for test cases are stock servicestack.

Comment: Having your DTO class implement [`IRequiresRequestStream`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization) might be what you want?